# Run JAVA program at exact times repeatedly using ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java

I want schedule one java program to run at 15th,25th and 45th min of time every hour. For example:

17:15 , 17:25 , 17:45 , 18:15 and so on...

How can I acheive this using **ScheduledExecutorService**. I can see several examples which can trigger scripts after certain time intervals with respect to the time they are triggered using ScheduledExecutorService.

Can anyone suggest me relevent links and examples to get some idea

Comment: if its java program you should try `crontab` to trigger it, if  you want to execute methods in java program you should look at `@Scheduled` of springframework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a way to schedule a `Timer` with uneven intervals.  However, it is relatively straightforward to schedule a `Timer` to execute at fixed intervals.

For your case, you could schedule three timers, one for `:15`, one for `:25`, and one for `:45` past the hour:

```
public class TaskTest {
    public static scheduleTask(int interval) {
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int date = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
        int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int hourScheduled = hour;

        // if we are past the scheduled time then schedule for the next hour
        if (minute > interval) {
            ++hourScheduled;
        }
        cal.set(year, month, date, hourScheduled, interval);
        long initialDelay = cal.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (initialDelay < 0) {
            initialDelay = 0L;
        }
        // schedule each job for once per hour
        int period = 60*60*1000;

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        SomeTask someTask = new SomeTask();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(someTask, initialDelay, period);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // schedule for the 15th, 25th and 45th min of time every hour
        scheduleTask(15);
        scheduleTask(25);
        scheduleTask(45);
    }
}

public class SomeTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to trigger your code at some time point, not periodically, I think there are several choices:

1. if your program run under Linux or other systems which support crontab, then crontab is a good choice.

   We could create multi cron job to achieve your target:

   use command "crontab -e" to edit cron jobs:

> 15 * * * * /java_path/java your_program parameters
>
> 25 * * * * /java_path/java your_program parameters
>
> 35 * * * * /java_path/java your_program parameters
>
> 45 * * * * /java_path/java your_program parameters

2. if you don't want to use crontab, and you just want a pure java solution, quartz will help you.

   quartz could let you configure cron triggers which are little like crontab under Linux.

   please refer to http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html to get more information.
3. At last, you want a pure java, and lightweight solution, you could simply use Java Timer and TimerTask, such as:

   public class App {

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Timer timer = new Timer();
       TimerTask tt = new SchedulerTask();
       DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
       Date triggerTime = null;
       try {
           triggerTime = df.parse("2016-04-12 13:15:00");
       } catch (ParseException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       timer.schedule(tt, triggerTime, 3600*1000);
   }

   static class SchedulerTask extends TimerTask {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           System.out.println("I am running at " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
       }
   }
   ```

   }

you could create 4 tasks like the task above, trigger at 13:15, 13:25, 13:35, 13:45 and each task runs once for every hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule same runnable with fixed 1hour interval & delay should be variable based on current time.

Example current time 6:10 than delay for your first schedule will be 5min(6:15), for second schedule 5+10=15 min(6:25).
like that you can create multiple schedule each with one hour delays.

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MultipleScheduler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     Runnable task = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " Task executed");

            }
        };

        ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        int BaseDelay = getInitialDelay();

        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, BaseDelay, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, BaseDelay + 10, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, BaseDelay + 30, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);



    }

    static int getInitialDelay() {
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int minute=cal.get(cal.MINUTE);


        int delay=0;
         //some logic to calculate delay    updated delay should be returned

        return delay;
    }
}
```

Comment: using delay has its flaw. It depends on the time when the respective java program has been triggered.

Comment: @Shashank if you try to create that delay calculation it will not take that much time , just  let me know if you cant calculate delay and post me the code you have tried ,i will provide you the same,but i suggest you should try at least.

Comment: it is just logical part remain ,if you try than it will boost your logic ,or mine if you not going to try it.